# biblatex custom style no numbering in bibliography

Tags: biblatex

se community,

i would like to write my masters thesis in tex using miktex + texstudio. i wrote my bachelors thesis using bibtex and now switched to biblatex + biber. i was searching for a citation style for biblatex that is as close as possible to iso 690. this is the closest match i could find: https://github.com/domhardt/BibLaTeX-DIN1505/blob/master/din.bbx

Unfortunately, there is no numbering in the bibliography.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage
    [
        backend=biber,
        citestyle=numeric,
        bibstyle=DIN
%       style=numeric
    ]
    {biblatex}

\addbibresource{LiteraturMWE.bib} 

\begin{document}

    zitat buch \cite{book} \\

    \printbibliography
    \nocite{*}

\end{document}
```

And my .bib file

```
@article{article,
    author  = {Autor Artikel}, 
    title   = {Name des Artikels},
    journal = {Zeitschrift Name},
    year    = 1993,

    number  = 2,
    pages   = {201-213},
    month   = 7,
    note    = {Notiz}, 
    volume  = 4
}

@book{book,
    author    = {Autor Buch}, 
    title     = {Buch Titel},
    publisher = {Herausgeber Name},
    year      = 1993,

    volume    = 4,
    series    = 10,
    address   = {Adresse},
    edition   = 3,
    month     = 7,
    note      = {Notiz},
    isbn      = {3257227892}
}
```

If possible, i would like to have numbers like `style=numeric`. Is there a way to implement this at some point in the DIN.bbx? Is this even the right place for making this change?

Thanks in advance,
Sklibbi

Comment: Hi and welcome, isn't that something for the issue tracker of the repository?

Comment: You can also chheck out `https://github.com/michal-h21/biblatex-iso690`. Actually reading the DIN/ISO might be another interesting thing to do.

Comment: The repository you are linking to defines a author-year citation style with an accompanying bibliographystyle. A numeric citation style along with a non-numeric bib-style doesn't make much sense.